# MongoDB: $pull / $unset with multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

### Example Document:

```
{
  _id: 42,
  foo: {
    bar: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
  }
}
```

### The query:

I'd like to *"remove all entries from `foo.bar` that are `$lt: 4` and the first matching entry that matches `$eq: 5`"*. **Important:** The `$eq` part must only remove a **single** entry!

I have a working solution, that uses 3 update queries, but that's too much for that simple task. Nevertheless, here's what I did so far:

**1.** Find the first entry matching `$eq: 5` and `$unset` it. (As you know: `$unset` doesn't remove it. It just sets it to `null`):

```
update(
  { 'foo.bar': 5 },
  { $unset: { 'foo.bar.$': 1 } } 
)
```

**2.** `$pull` all entries `$eq: null`, so that former `5` is really gone:

```
update(
  {},
  { $pull: { 'foo.bar': null } } 
)
```

**3.** `$pull` all entries `$lt: 4`:

```
update(
  {},
  { $pull: { 'foo.bar': { $lt: 4 } } } 
)
```

### Resulting Document:

```
{
  _id: 42,
  foo: {
    bar: [4, 5]
  }
}
```

### Ideas and Thoughts:

- Extend query **1.**, so that it will `$unset` the entries `$lt: 4` and one entry `$eq: 5`. Afterwards we can execute query **2.** and there's no need for query **3.**.
- Extend query **2.** to `$pull` everything that matches `$or: [{$lt: 4}, {$eq: 5}]`. Then there's no need for query **3.**.
- Extend query **2.** to `$pull` everything that is `$not: { $gte: 4 }`. This expression should match `$lt: 4` **and** `$eq: null`.

I already tried to implement those queries, but sometimes it complained about the query syntax and sometimes the query did execute and just removed nothing.

Would be nice, if someone has a working solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I get your full meaning of this, but to "bulk" update documents you can always take this approach in addition the oringal [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and adding some "detection" of which documents you need to remove "duplicate" `5` from:

```js
// Remove less than four first
db.collection.update({},{ "$pull": { "foo.bar": { "$lt": 4 } } },{ "multi": true });

// Initialize Bulk
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderdBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

// Detect and cycle documents with duplicate five to be removed
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Project a "reduced" array and calculate if the same size as orig
    { "$project": { 
         "foo.bar": { "$setUnion": [ "$foo.bar", [] ] },
         "same": { "$eq": [
             { "$size": {  "$setUnion": [ "$foo.bar", [] ] } },
             { "$size": "$foo.bar" }
         ] }
    }},
    // Filter the results that were unchanged
    { "$match": { "same": true } }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id })
        .updateOne({ "$set": { "foo.bar": doc.foo.bar.sort() } });
    count++;

    // Execute per 1000 processed and re-init
    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderdBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clean up any batched
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

That trims out anything less than "4" and all duplicates where a "duplicate" is detected from the difference in "set" length.

If you just want values of `5` removed as duplicates you can take a similar logic approach to the detection and modification, just not with "set operators" that remove anything that is a "duplicate" making it a valid "set".

At any rate, some detection strategy is going to be better than iterating updates until "all but one" value is gone.

---

Of course you can simplify your statements a little and remove one update operation, it's not pretty because `$pull` does not allow an `$or` condition in a query, but I hope you get the idea if this applies:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "foo.bar": 5 },
    { "$unset": { "foo.bar.$": 1 } },
    { "multi": true }
); // same approach

// So include all the values "less than four"
db.collection.update(
    { "foo.bar": { "$in": [1,2,3,null] } },
    { "$pull": { "foo.bar": { "$in": [1,2,3,null] } }},
    { "multi": true }
);
```

It's a bit less processing but of course those need to be exact integer values. Otherwise stick with the three updates you are doing. Better than cycling in code.

For reference, the "nicer" syntax that will unfortunately **not work** would be something like this:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { 
        "$or": [
            { "foo.bar": { "$lt": 4 } },
            { "foo.bar": null }
        ]
    },
    { 
        "$pull": { 
            "$or": [
                { "foo.bar": { "$lt": 4 } },
                { "foo.bar": null }
            ]
        }
    },
    { "multi": true }
);
```

Probably worth a JIRA issue, but I suspect mostly because the array element is not the "first" argument directly following `$pull`.

Comment: Ah sorry. This is not about removing duplicates. It's really just "remove everything below 4 and one (or zero) entry equal to 5".

Comment: @BenjaminM please define "one or zero" precicely. Do you mean that if there are multiple values for `5` left as in `[4,5,5,5]` then you want the result to be `[4,5,5]`? Or is it something else?

Comment: If the condition is `$lt: 4` or `$eq: 5`, then here are some examples: `[] -> []`, `[2] -> []`, `[4] -> [4]`, `[5] -> []`, `[1,1,2,2,3,4,4] -> [4,4]`,  `[1,4,5,5,5] -> [4,5,5]`, `[3,5] -> []`. In words: "every entry below 4 and one entry equal to 5 (if there is any entry equal to 5)"

Comment: @BenjaminM Got it. As noted the "nice" thing here would be if  `$or` would be accepted in a `$pull`. But it isn't, so improvisation is required.

Comment: Sadly your query using `$in` won't work, because in my real world screnario those numbers are `ISODates` and I need `$lt` for that to work :(

Comment: @BenjaminM Well the points are explained there of what will work and what does not. As mentioned your best approach where you cannot exact match via `$in` ( since `$lt` options will not be accepted witin `$in` ) is to do what you are doing right now. You also cannot do `{ "$pull": { "foo.bar": { "$lt": 4, "$gte": null } } }` since that is an **and** condition and nothing would match. Some might find the analysis and conclusions here useful.

Comment: I now got it working somehow, the "trick" is to use an array of documents instead of an array of values: `foo.bar: [ {baz: 1}, {baz: 2}, ... ]`. Now this update **works**: `$pull: {'foo.bar':{'baz':{$not:{$gte:5}}}}` while this **does not** work: `$pull: {'foo.bar':{$not:{$gte:5}}}`. I don't understand why it can't apply the `$not` operator using a simple array of values.

Comment: @BenjaminM Well it will probably be closed as duplicate because I already submitted the issue yesterday. Good for submitting though,[SERVER-1972](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19172). Please upvote the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the [**`Array.prototype.splice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) methods

The `filter()` method creates a news array with `foo.bar` values `$lt: 4` then you use the `splice` method to remove those values and the first value equal `5` from `foo.bar`

```js
var idx = [];
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){ 
    idx = doc.foo.bar.filter(function(el){  
        return el < 4;
    }); 
    for(var i in idx){   
        doc.foo.bar.splice(doc.foo.bar.indexOf(idx[i]), 1); 
    } 
    doc.foo.bar.splice(doc.foo.bar.indexOf(5), 1); 
    db.collection.save(doc);
} )
```

Comment: But this is'n a safe operation, if there are some inserts to this array in the meantime.

Comment: So for the record and I think @BenjaminM will agree this is about "server" processing. You can always do thins in the client code, but it's not really efficient. Updates should not need to cycle and "test" every document in a collection to be effective. And aggreed "is is not safe". `.save()` can "overwrite".